# Invalid read size error in a map using valgrind

Tags: c++, debugging, dictionary, valgrind, segmentation-fault

I have this code for filling a table but I keep getting a segmentation error. I'm at my wit's end trying to find what the error could be. My function takes in 2 maps and iterates through them to find the common strings. It takes the int value of these commons strings and puts it in a table to count the number of times there are common strings.

```
myMap findTable(mapGraph * dbgraph1, mapGraph * dbgraph2)
{
typedef mapGraph::const_iterator iter;
typedef myMap::const_iterator mapiter;

iter it1 = dbgraph1->begin();
iter it2 = dbgraph2->begin();
int count =0;
myMap * newTable = NULL;

//iterating through the 2 samples of dbgraphs
while (it1 != dbgraph1->end() && it2 != dbgraph2->end())
{
    //a match is found for 2 strings
    if (it1->first == it2->first)
    {
        //the component ids of first sample
        int compdb1 = it1->second->comp;

        //the component ids of second sample
        int compdb2 = it2->second->comp;

        //inserting the component ids and counts in the map
        newTable->insert(make_pair(make_pair(compdb1, compdb2), count));
        count++;

        for (mapiter it = newTable->begin(); it != newTable->end(); it++)
        {
            printf("%i %i\t %i\n", it->first.first, it->first.second, it->second);
        }

        it1++;
        it2++;

    }

    //match not found
    else
        it1++;
        it2++;

}
printf("\nCLEAR\n");
return newTable;
}
```

This is the error:

```
Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
Invalid read of size 8
Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
Access not within mapped region at address 0x10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newTable` is `NULL`:

```
myMap * newTable = NULL;
```

and is never assigned to a valid object before:

```
newTable->insert(make_pair(make_pair(compdb1, compdb2), count));
```

Dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is undefined behaviour. Either dynamicaly allocate a `myMap` instance for `newTable`:

```
myMap* newTable = new myMap(); // Remember to delete later.
```

or use a stack allocated instance:

```
myMap newTable;
```

This is an error:

```
//match not found
    else
        it1++;
        it2++;
```

resulting in `it2` being incremented on every iteration of the loop and will result in `++` being called on an `end()` iterator. Change to:

```
//match not found
    else
    {
        it1++;
        it2++;
    }
```

Or to simplify the code just increment the iterators at one place in the loop as they are incremented always (in each branch of the `if\else`).

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean by: Either dynamicaly allocate a myMap instance for newTable or use a stack allocated instance.

Comment: @sumrania: please consider reading "C++ for dummies"-like book first...

Comment: @hmjd I have tried using a stack allocated instance (I just didn't know it was called that). I still get same error. Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: @sumrania, are you initialising `it1` and `it2` somewhere?

Comment: @hmjd yes, I added some more code

Comment: it works!! thanks a lot! What is a good way to identify such logic errors on my own the next time?

Comment: @sumrania, remove chunks of the code until the fault goes away. Then readd the code piece by piece until you can isolate the problem. Its not always straightforward though...